# Automatically adding Filter control in excel

Tags: excel, filter, autofilter, vba

I'm very new to VBA.
I want to code to automatically add the filter control in all of my cells that have data when the worksheet is opened.

I created a macro and used that code but it doesn't do anything.

Here is my code to add a filter control to all the columns:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("my example1").Cells.Select
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("my example1").Selection.AutoFilter
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you add some sample data as well, please?

Comment: I think that the `AutoFilter` command toggles the filter on and off. So before you call it, ensure that Autofilter is off by using `.AutoFilterMode = False`.

Comment: also, might be better to use `CurrentRegion.Autofilter` rather than `Selection.Autofilter` as in your code snippet you are selecting **all the cells in the sheet**

Comment: Sample Data - very basic:

Country: England, Frace,Ital
Dealer_Cost: 37853, 4631, 41235
Retail_cost: 45319, 5610, 51065
Sales: 12000, 0, 302000

I've tried the Autofiltermode = false
and the currentreiong.autofilter and neither work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more specific about WHAT you are selecting before you filter,
e.g.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("my example1").Range("A1:Z1")
```

or the whole top row :

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("my example1").Range("1:1")
```

and, as mentioned above, check that autofilter is off:

```
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting the filter code in the sheet_change event.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("YTD Detail").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub